# SQL Exception was unhandled-An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcommand, sqlexception, sqldataadapter

SQL Exception was unhandled-An unhandled exception of type **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException** occurred in System.Data.dll

```
 public DataSet getCustomers()
    {
        string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
        objConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer '"                                                  ,
                                              objConnection);
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        objAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

        objConnection.Close();
        return objDataSet;

    }
```

Comment: Please provide more details around the problem, for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an extra apostrophe after Customer `' "`:

```
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer '", objConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ' from query command:

```
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer" , objConnection);
```

Comment: You put the same answer, 3 hours later??

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing your code in a Try Catch:

```
        public DataSet getCustomers()
    {
        try
        {
            string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString();
            SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
            objConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer '",
                                                  objConnection);
            DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
            objAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

            objConnection.Close();
            return objDataSet;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Write(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

ex.Message will be: **Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''**.

Just remove the **'** after Customer